# Multiple View is getting loaded in verification of session variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code

        $this->is_logged_in();
    }

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in=$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true){

            //$this->load->view('notlogin');
            $this->load->view('admin_login');
            //echo "you dont have permission to access this area";
        }
    }

    function index()
    {       
        $this->load->view('admin_login');
        //die();
    }

    function adminlogin()
    {
        $this->load->model('loginmodel');
        $query=$this->loginmodel->verify();

        if($query==true){

            $data=array(
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in'=>true

                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('Login/loginarea');
        }
        else
        {
            //$this->is_logged_in();
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    public function loginarea()
    {
        $this->load->view('mainadmin');   
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Here two function `__construct` and `index` is loading the same view twice. I don't how to logically correct this. I am checking `is_logged_in` variable is true or not: if true then load admin area or else admin login page. But `index` function is also getting executed along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your controller, it will always execute the constructor and the function you have specified in the second segment or by default, `index()`.

In your case, if we assume your URL is http://example.com/index.php/Login

The first thing to be executed is the constructor which calls `$this->is_logged_in();`

If we assume that the login failed, you load the view with this call `$this->load->view('admin_login');`

That's it for the constructor.

Then codeigniter call the default function `index()` which also loads a view `$this->load->view('admin_login');`

So, that's why your view appears two times.

Imo, the easiest way to fix this is by removing the code in `index()`. You are not doing anything special in that function and the view is loaded inside `is_logged_in()` when the constructor is executed.

However, I don't understand why do you check the user status in the controller supposed to authenticate people.

It shouldn't be done that way imho :

Actually, you check if the user **is not** logged. Instead, I would have have check if the user **is** logged then I redirect to the admin area or whatever it is.
This way, `index()` will be the function that displays `admin_login` and the constructor via `is_logged_in()` displays the other view.

Comment: Ok Thanks...but just now i found out that my session in not working ,because when i fetch the username or is_logged_in data then nothing is returned.Please check